# DocuSign Connect (Delete Signers)

Tags: docusignapi

I am not receiving events for Delete of signers.
Is this an expected behaviour of DocuSign Connect?

These are my steps:

1. Log in as sender and created the envelope with 4 signers
2. Click on the email link as the signer and opened the envelope
3. Signed the envelope as the signer
4. Log in as sender and deleted one of the remaining 3 signers (This is missing from my Connect event)

I received XML messages for steps 1-3.
However, there was no event trigger for step 4.
I am monitoring this under both Connect Logs and Failures.

I have every event enabled under my Connect Configuration.
Is it expected to not receive an event in this case?
If not, any suggestions on how I can debug why I am not receiving messages?

Just another finding:
An event is triggered for the New Experience.
This behavior is only observed for the Classic Experience.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the behavior you're seeing is by design. i.e., the "Recipient Deleted" action does not correlate to any of the *events* that can trigger a DocuSign Connect notification.  The events that *can* trigger a DocuSign Connect notification are shown in the Connect configuration UI:

[image]

As this screenshot shows, there is no event that correlates to the "Recipient Deleted" action.

If your application needs to know if/when a recipient is removed from an Envelope, you could implement a process that periodically polls in-progress envelopes ([List Envelope Recipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/)) with the goal of detecting if/when a recipient has been deleted. This obviously isn't ideal, as it wouldn't be a real-time notification, but it's likely your only option, given that DocuSign Connect does not currently support notifications for "Recipient Deleted".

---

UPDATE #1

---

Interestingly, I've verified the behavior that you've described in your Comment below. I tested the following scenario in both the "New" UI and the "Classic" UI:

- Created/sent an Envelope with 2 recipients (sequential routing order: 1, 2)
- Immediately thereafter (i.e., while still pending response from the first signer), I *corrected* the Envelope to delete the second recipient (routing order=2).

Conducting the steps above using the "New" Smartsheet UI triggers a Connect Notification ("Envelope Sent"), while conducting the exact same stepsusing the "Classic" Smartsheet UI does ***not*** trigger any notification. This behavior inconsistency seems like a bug to me -- perhaps someone with DocuSign can chime in to confirm/explain.

Comment: I was told that this action of deleting a recipient should still trigger a "Envelope Sent" event to DocuSign Connect so I am not sure if this is a designed behavior or if i am missing out something in my configuration.

Comment: if it is designed to be as such, I can poll the envelopes for this but of course this is not desired both functionally and technically and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Just another finding.. This works for New Experience but not Classic Experience.

Comment: Very interesting that it works for the New Experience but not for the Classic Experience.  Let me do some testing here and get back to you.  In the meantime, perhaps someone from DocuSign will chime in.

Comment: Added "Update #1" to my answer.